# Update query does not replace with nothing?

Tags: mysql

This query works fine:

```
UPDATE duration_events b
JOIN meteor_events p
ON p.event_id = b.event_id
SET b.eventdes = p.eventdes;
```

so if I enter some text in `meteor_events` and `eventdes` for a particular record then the text in the corresponding record in `duration_events` gets updated.

How ever if I then remove the text from `meteor_events` and  `eventdes` and run the query its not replaced in `duration_events` - I assumed it would simple repace the contents of the field ?

Comment: What do you mean by removing the text in meteor_events? Do you remove the record or just set eventdes to null or to an empty string?

Comment: no the record stays I simply remove the text so its an empty string - i thought if I then ran the query it would copy the empty string to the corresponding field in the duration_events table \ record

Comment: Works as expected for me. Perhaps you could provide sample data.